# Assigning pubnub lobby to a specified group of users.

Tags: ios, ios7, pubnub

Hi i am working on an ios application that uses pubnub for several different forms of messaging. Right now I need guidance on how I would go about setting a system a selected user is setup with his/her own public channel where anyone with access to the specified lobby could chat with the user. So lets say for example there is a public speaker at an event. All users that are given the specified code in the audience would be able to send the speaker messages. From a user interface stand point:

- user have a view in the app that requests a code (i.e. speaker3)
- user inputs code and is transitioned to a 1way chat view that lets the user send messages.
- user is not able to recieve messages from the speaker or see messages that have been sent by other users.
- speaker recieves all the messages from users

Questions:

- Is this possible?
- what can I use to implement such a system using pubnub?
- does anyone have any ideas on how I could implement such a system?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 2):

It's totally possible, PubNub is perfect for this.

In this case your user must know the speakers channel name, it's important because without this she is not able to send him a message. Since a user knows the speaker's channel id, she can send him a message.

> user is not able to recieve messages from the speaker or see messages
>   that have been sent by other users.

You can do it in different ways, but it's a UI related stuff, not PubNub. Originally, if sampleUser listens sampleSpeakers channel she will hear everything on that channel, but you can display only sampleUser's messages in the user interface.

> speaker recieves all the messages from users

In this case you just display the content from the speakers channel history with the [Playback and Storage](http://www.pubnub.com/docs/objective-c/iOS/overview/storage-playback.html#_using_history_api).

So the point is that PubNub will be a perfect choice, BUT i shattered rivers of tears over a couple nights until i understood it. It's much easier than it looks like, in the most cases (99%) when you think that something is a PubNub related problem/question, you will recognize it's just UI customization. After a message "arrived" to the client you need to sort it and display in the right way.

To get started please check this [guide](http://www.pubnub.com/docs/objective-c/iOS/ios-sdk.html). I recommend you to read everything on their site and the documentation at the Cocoa Docs. It doesn't matter if you don't need one of their features, you need to understand the whole concept.

Answer (score 0):

This is really easy to do.

Lats say that for concrete lecture speaker generate special code for authorised persons (that code actually will be name of the channel on which speaker's application will subscribe and will wait for messages) and they will use that code to send messages. So, authorised persons enter this code and you will use it with PubNub send message API as channel name - in this case, they will send messages, but never will see any messages from other persons (trey are not subscribed on this channel and just send messages right to it).